# Return largest value in a group

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rank

I am trying to index and return the proceeds value that corresponds with the largest sale tranche of a given product.

The following spreadsheet is a very simplified version of the sheet I am dealing with.

[image: Example]

Take, for example, product 2. Product 2 has been sold in 2 sales tranches (one 40% of the product, the other 60% of the product). I need to, in Column D, input the proceeds value for the largest sale tranche of each product. So, for product 2, the 60% sale tranche is the largest sale tranche, and the corresponding proceeds value would be 40.

I have tried using multiple formulae including `RANK`, `COUNTIF`,`INDEX(MATCH())` and cannot seem to work out how to do it.

My first thought was to have a helper column with a formula something along the lines of

`COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,RANK(B2,$B$2:$B$11),)`

and then I could easily return the value I need with a simple `IF` function in the next column.

But obviously this function is nonesense, is missing a term and doesn't work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. So for Cell D2 is suppose to be 500, D3 = 40, D4 = 30, D5 = 300, D6 = 100 and so on............?

Comment: I think all product 2 lines (D3,D4) would =40 since it corresponds with the 60% (highest % sold)

Comment: actually my question was going to be what does OP want in rows where the row is not the maximum sale %?  Does he want the value from the max displayed, 0 display, or "" displayed?

Comment: "" can be displayed if the row does not represent the largest tranche sale. So D2=100, D4=40, D6=300, D8=40

Comment: However, It doesn't matter if D2=100, D3=40, D4=40, D5=300, D6=300, D7=300, D8=40, D9=40, D10=40, D11=40 as that will still be easy to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  It is an array formula so it has to be entered by pressing **ctrl+shift+enter**

Formula entered in D2 then copied down.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$B$2:$B$11,0),1),IF($A$2:$A$11=A2,$B$2:$B$11,0),0))
```

Another option with helper column

helper (In D2) returns 0 if its the maximum row

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,">"&B2)
```

Solution (E2)

```
=AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$11,$A$2:$A$11,A2,$D$2:$D$11,0)
```

Used averageifs in case there are 2 equally high values it would return the average otherwise it is just the average of 1 cell.

Comment: Thanks for this - it works well. Is there no simpler way? Or way that I could use helper columns and not have to use array formulae?

Comment: Great solution - exactly what I was looking. I used `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,">"&B2)>=1,0,1)` so that I only retrieve a 1 if it is the largest value. I then used `=IF(D2=1,C2,0)` to retrieve my values

Comment: I didn't see the comment that you could have blanks in the non max row.  You don't really need the helper column then. `=if(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,">"&B2)=0,C2,"")`

Comment: I realised this just as I wrote the response - I have exactly the same formula as you now. Simple when you know how!

Answer (score 0):

Copy below formula to cell D2

```
=MAX(OFFSET($C$1,MATCH(A1,A:A,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(A:A,A1),1))
```

Then copy D2 then paste down

Above formula will only work when Column A numbers are sorted

Comment: Thanks for this - it does work, but unfortunately Column A numbers will not always be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel comfortable with VBA, you can write a function to do the work for you. If the drop the following code into a module, you can specify a range of values you want to group by (in your case the list of product numbers), the criteria you want to filter by (which product number you want to evaluate), and the values you want to compare.  By saving each range into an array, you can iterate through the list of values and find the largest value that has the product number you've specified.

```
Function Maxif(GroupRange As Range, Criteria As Variant, ValuesRange As Range)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Groupings As Variant
    Dim Value As Variant

    Groupings = Array()
    Values = Array()

    Groupings = GroupRange
    Values = ValuesRange

    Maxif = "#N/A"

    For i = 1 To UBound(Groupings, 1)
        If Maxif = "#N/A" Then
            If Groupings(i, 1) = Criteria Then
                Maxif = Values(i, 1)
            Else:
            End If
        Else:
            If (Groupings(i, 1) = Criteria And Values(i, 1) > Maxif) Then
                Maxif = Values(i, 1)
            Else:
            End If
        End If
    Next i 
End Function
```

It follows the same logic as countif, sumif, etc. So Maxif(A2:A11, A3, C2:C11) will return 60%, the max value for product 2.

From there, if you need to find the proceeds, can you insert a column before column A, concatenate product and % sold in that column, and then do a vlookup on the product concatenated with the max % sold to find the corresponding proceeds.

E.g.:

[image]

And then your summary table would look like:

[image]

This will work no matter how you sort the sheet.